# Flex 3 / ColdFusion Session Issue?

Tags: apache-flex, session, coldfusion

Alright so this is an odd one... I have an application built in ColdFusion with a lot of the interactivity done with Flex. When a user logs in, there are session variables, as well as the client session that is evoked. When you browse to any given Flex Application, the variables are read in a used accordingly... however, on Windows (it seems XP and maybe others) for some reason session information like USER are randomly undefined...

Could this be an issue with the session timing out? Even if I force a logout and log back in, it doesn't really seem to fix the issue... mind you, I cannot duplicate the bug myself, but it constantly happens on PCs.

Comment: This really depends on many factors, from session management on Coldfusion side to browser, version of Flash player etc. I guess you'll have to find exact scenario when it happens.

Comment: Flash Player uses different session from the container browser.  Maybe that's what you're experiencing?

Comment: @Henry Could you be more specific? For all I know, that could be the problem.

Comment: if you use cookie based session, then cookie flex uses will be different than the cookie of the browser use on the same page.

Comment: @Henry well, I'm not dealing with cookies within flex... At least not intentionally.

Comment: are you sure? are you passing CFID/CFSESSIONID as param in flex webvservice calls?  Session is, usually, made possible by cookies

Comment: @Henry My Flex applications are just interacting with the server when variables or parameters are changed or saved... should I be passing CFSESSIONID along somehow as well?

Comment: yes, pass both CFID and CFSESSIONID as URL param if you want to use the same session as the parent browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue (though there were smaller issues that Henry pointed out for me) was url specific paths.

The underlining issue is that each server is different. If you migrate your software to a new server, don't assume that everything will work under the new conditions.